# jquery override event

Tags: jquery, overriding

I have an anchor like this

```
<a href='#' onclick='return showform(this)'>click me</a>
```

But I want to be able to override the onclick function, how to do this in jquery?

because it seems when I add

```
$('a').click( function() { alert('hi there!'); } );
```

the new click handler is not overriding the old one

Comment: why <a href='#' onclick='return showform(this)'>click me</a>?
structure/content and behavior should be separate. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: I have removed the onclick function and rely everything on jquery because it seems more flexible that way...
Thank you all for the responses :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$("a").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Comment: Old post, but this is definitely the method that has been working for me within the ready() function

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too!

Answer (score 22):

In your case the onCick event is overriding the jQuery one. What you might be able to do is:

```
$('a').unbind('click').click(function(){
    alert('why hello there children.');
})
```

But I believe this would have to be included after the

```
<a href='#' onclick='return showform(this)'>click me</a>
```

That said, you should really not be using onClicks anyway... it makes the code really hard to maintain and change (as you have found out).

Comment: If you're following Yahoo, all scripts are included at the end of the page anyway...

Comment: That is true, I figured I should point that part out though, as the last onclick event should override the rest no?

Comment: It depends when $('a').unbind() is called. If it's in $(document).ready() then it could be in the `head` and still work.

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I think that unbind can't remove a handler that hasn't been set up with jQuery.

Comment: Ya, I am not sure about that either, I tend to not write my code with onClicks.

Comment: Thanks for this code @SeanJA it was useful to me :) `function` will need to be `function()` for the above code to work. I tried to edit but couldn't find 6 other characters to change

Comment: @SSH This: Whoops. Fixed it (surprised no one else saw that...)

Answer (score 10):

If you're using jQuery like this, you don't want any handlers in the HTML. Can't you just remove the `onClick` attribute?

If you're worried about breaking stuff, search and replace on:

```
 onclick='return showform(this)'
```

and replace with

```
class='showform'
```

Then you can do:

```
$('a.showform').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return showform(this);
});
```

which will keep your existing handlers working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for it, but you should only do this when you really need to. The plugin allows you to call the original function or ignore/replace it entirely

[jQuery Override Plugin](https://jqueryoverride.codeplex.com/)

```
$(divElementObj).override('onclick', 'click', function(...));
```